# success on ajax loads html page of hyperlink

Tags: jquery, button, hyperlink, onclick, attr

I have a button that when clicked it triggers an AJAX call.
On success, I wish to update a hyperlink href. However, with the code below, it not only updates the href, it actually also loads the page and spits out the content of the link on the screen.

```
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     $(this).hide();
     $("#create_inv_msg").show();
     $("#create_inv_msg").fadeIn(400).html('saving...');
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sales/AJAX_sales.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
           if (result!="GAGAL")
           {
              $("#create_inv_msg").html("SUKSES");
              $("#sales_edit_link").attr("href","sales_edit.ui.php?sales_id=" + result);
              $("#sales_edit_link").text(result);
              $("#sales_edit_link").show();
              $("#new_POS_btn").show();
           }
        }
     });
```

Is this a normal behavior? I only wanted to show a hyperlink after successful AJAX call.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like some error on my AJAX server code. Problem solved. Thanks Lundstromski for helping out with the Codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the behavior you are after? [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Lundstromski/pen/ZEWJyQp)

You also seem to miss a quotation mark in the url-parameter:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: sales/AJAX_sales.php",
```

Comment: Sorry, I have the quotation mark correct on my code but forgot to put it when I asked the question. But yes, that behavior is what I am after....however, on my code, result is just a string "FAIL" or the sales ID. 
Instead of just printing the hyperlink of the sales ID, it also loads the content of the hyperlink and display it. I don't see any difference between my code and yours other than the source of the AJAX.